# Brand new Ubuntu 14.04.2 Docker container + Nginx: connection refused on port 80

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker

I followed the instructions at [Digital Ocean's "How To Install Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts), which states that Nginx should be running as soon as it is installed, but the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.2
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN apt-get -y install nginx
RUN curl http://127.0.0.1 | grep "Welcome to nginx!"
```

gives me this error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

To reproduce this:

- make sure Docker is installed on your host system
- insert the code above into `/whatever/path/Dockerfile`
- type 'cd /whatever/path/ && Docker build .'

This will build the docker container using Ubuntu, install Nginx, then try to connect to 127.0.0.1:80 returns the Nginx welcome page. That is where the "connection refused" error occurs.

My question is: how can I call "curl http://127.0.0.1 from within my container and get a response?

This issue on my project is https://github.com/dcycleproject/dcyclebox/issues/1

Comment: Something else is bound to that port alread (e.g. Apache)?

Comment: as @marekful suggested, you may want to check if the port is in use. Try running `netstat -an | grep :80 | grep LISTEN`

Comment: @Jpatrick, it is a docker image creation, nothing is running there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to start `nginx` first:

`RUN service nginx start && curl http://127.0.0.1 | grep "Welcome to nginx!"`

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, having RUN service nginx start and RUN curl http://localhost | grep "Welcome to nginx!" on separate lines causes the port 80 connection refused problem, but running them on the same line with && works!

Answer (score 1):

Instruction on digital ocean talking about OS with running services which are not running in docker container (and they should not). When you building image you only installing necessary software. Then you should run container based on this image - and usually only one process is running in container. Look at official nginx image for example - https://github.com/dockerfile/nginx/blob/master/Dockerfile

Also it is a bad practice to run apt-get update and apt-get install in different RUN commands - https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#run